# How to make document dimensions match printouts

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, printing, office365, hp

I would like to be able to specific dimensions in MS Word (*) and have them match in the real world. This seems straight forward, but when I try this they don't match.

A minimal example is an empty word document with a 1x1 table and specify a side of 5 cm by 5 cm. The paper in my printer (HP OfficeJet Pro 9010) matches the document in Word (A4). All settings like margins are default. Printer settings are default and scaling is set to 'no scaling'. Printing and measuring this the box comes out to 4.737 cm on both sides (~5.3% off). This is too inaccurate for my application. **Is there a way to make the dimensions in Word match the dimensions of the subsequent print?**

* Microsoft® Word for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2401 Build 16.0.17231.20084) 64-bit

[image]

Comment: Some printers don't print exactly edge-to-edge, and slightly scale down each page. Your model does say it will do "borderless" printing on A4 (but only on photo paper?). HP printers usually have some tools in the app like "Calibrate the Device" or "Align the printer" that may help. Otherwise, it should also be easy enough to bump up the sizes by 5.3% in Word

Comment: Try to create a square via Insert->Shapes->select rectangle and then choose dimensions

Comment: In Word *File > Options > Advanced > Print*, is "Scale content for A4 or 8.5 x 11" paper sizes" unchecked?

Comment: @harrymc. "Scale content for A4 or 8.5 x 11" paper sizes" is checked. Should it be?

Comment: @Cpt.Whale I tried printing a rectangle that is 5.27x5.27 cm. It came out 4.95 cm (close enough). So the simple scaling of everything works.

Comment: @Romeo Ninov see above. Using shapes does not fix the issue

Comment: @TokeFaurby, I saw you use tables, not shapes. And check in printing dialog about autoscale, scaleup, scaledown to fit the paper.

Comment: Try to uncheck to have no scaling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [@harrymc](https://superuser.com/users/8672/harrymc) the following works.

Uncheck the following:

- Word File > Options > Advanced > Print, is "Scale content for A4 or 8.5 x 11" paper sizes"

[image]

Furthermore: The dimensions of tables and shapes are the same (i.e. if they are the same dimensions in Word they will come out the same dimensions)